# Dynamically Typing Context Properties with Enum Autocompletion

Tags: typescript

I have this "context" object that contains sub-objects, each having a "type" key:

```
const context = {
  transferOptions: {
    label: 'Headquarters Transfer',
    type: 'string',
    possibleValues: [ // 'possibleValues' is optional 
      { label: 'Same jurisdiction transfer', value: HeadQuarterTransferType.SameJurisdiction },
      { label: 'Different jurisdiction transfer', value: HeadQuarterTransferType.OtherJurisdiction }
    ]
  },
  newCity: { // an another sub-object of type "string" but without the key "possibleValues"
        label: 'Blabla',
        type: 'string'
    },
  newZipcode: {
    label: 'blabla',
    type: 'number'
  },
  effectiveDate: {
    label: 'Effective Date of Headquarters Transfer',
    type: 'Date'
  }, 
  // ... etc 
};

enum HeadQuarterTransferType {
  SameJurisdiction = 'sameJurisdiction',
  OtherJurisdiction = 'otherJurisdiction'
}

// Type for context properties
type contextTypes = {
  [key in keyof typeof context]: (typeof context)[key]['type'] extends 'string'
    ? string
    : (typeof context)[key]['type'] extends 'number'
      ? number
      : (typeof context)[key]['type'] extends 'boolean'
        ? boolean
        : (typeof context)[key]['type'] extends 'Date'
          ? string
          : never;
};

const typedContext = context as contextTypes;

// Example usage
typedContext.effectiveDate; // it's working, with autocompletion and the correct type in my IDE
```

Now, when a sub-object has the 'type' key set to 'string,' like "transferOptions," at runtime, the "transferOptions" property, which will be a 'string,' should only accept values from the 'possibleValues' array (if the array is defined). How can I dynamically type this?

```
const typedContext = context as contextTypes;
typedContext.transferOptions; // I would like to have autocompletion with the values of the HeadQuarterTransferType enum
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please [edit] this code to be a [mre] that behaves as you intend it to; your `contextTypes` type is full of `never` properties. Is that what you expected? If not, could you change it? I'm also not sure why it's a series of conditional types as opposed to a single indexed access like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WY2zbw).  In order to even get to the beginning of answering the question I'd need to start fixing things you're not asking about. Could you do that part instead? Thanks.